# OpenStreetMap Nominatim and LandUse

Tags: vb.net, openstreetmap

I have to code a function that will return the landuse of an address. So far, my solution is based on VB.Net and I'm using Nominatim to receive informations. In the result, I get the two attributes class and type, but I need the landuse-information.

Do you have any hints, how I can retreive this information? This site is a list of land usages in OSM: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:landuse

I got the shapefile from OSM, too, but I have no idea how I should use it in .Net. My try was to use Catfood.Shapefile, but I didn't found any landuse attributes in the polygons.

This is how I get longitude, latitude, class and type attributes:

```
        Dim Webbrowser1 As New WebBrowser
        Dim ci As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
        Dim latitude, longitude As Decimal
        Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
        Dim myReq As Net.HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(Net.WebRequest.Create(url), Net.HttpWebRequest)
        Dim webResponse As Net.HttpWebResponse = Nothing
        Try
            'Ergebnissatz von OpenStreetMaps laden
            webResponse = TryCast(myReq.GetResponse(), Net.HttpWebResponse)
        Catch
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        If webResponse IsNot Nothing Then
            If webResponse.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then
                doc.Load(webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            End If
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim geometry As System.Xml.XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("searchresults/place")
        latitude = Convert.ToDecimal(geometry.Attributes("lat").Value, ci)
        longitude = Convert.ToDecimal(geometry.Attributes("lon").Value, ci)
        Debug.Print(geometry.Attributes("class").Value.ToString)
        Debug.Print(geometry.Attributes("type").Value.ToString)
```

Comment: Any code you could share as mentionned in [mcve]

Comment: How can I share code when I'm looking for a solution to write the code?

Comment: because if you had read the [mcve] and [ask] you would have noticed that we don't just code for people we ask them to have a try. And you also said and you said so far my solution so you already have code to get the information :)

Comment: It will not get better if you repeat your link :-) I said I am searching for a solution to write my code, not to get code from the community :-) But you can find my try to get longitute, latitude, class and type attribudes in the edit. I hope you know the solution how to get the landuse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) is a geocoder and not intended to return other information. You will need an additional step. Use Nominatim to obtain the geographic position for you address. Afterwards use [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) to fetch all landuses around this geographic position.

Here is an example Overpass API query:

```
way(around:500,50.7,7.1)[landuse];
(._;>;);
out;
```

View the [result on overpass-turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/p6Q) (a web frontend for Overpass API). This query returns all [ways](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) that have a [landuse](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:landuse) tag and are within 500 meters of the coordinates 50.7,7.1.

Comment: Sounds good - very good. Now I will search for the way how to integrate this API in my .Net application. Thank you!

Comment: After searching for the use of your example now I know how to create the query url at runtime. So far I love it and I accept it of course :-) Just one more question: I tested with the around:500, for example with 10, but this was too few, there were no landuse in the answer. Is there a way to get the landuse for a point (lat/lon)? Thank you!

Comment: There is an [is_in](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Query_for_areas_.28is_in.29) query but it works only for areas. Areas are a special type introduced by Overpass API and are as far as I know based on named objects. Landuses usually don't have a name, so unfortunately you can't use this query for landuses. Maybe someone else with more Overpass knowledge comes up with a better solution? You can also try asking at http://gis.stackexchange.com/ or http://help.openstreetmap.org/ but in this case please mention your question here.

Comment: Follow up is here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240712/overpass-api-get-landuse-from-latitude-longitude/240751#240751. `is_in` would only be an option, in case you host your own Overpass instance and adjust area creation scripts.